# Get refresh token in google one tap

Tags: java, reactjs, google-oauth, google-one-tap

I am currently working on integrating Google Login into my web application. My goal is to obtain a refresh token, which would allow me to obtain a new ID token or access token when they expire after one hour. However, I have encountered an issue with Google One Tap, as it only provides an ID token and does not seem to offer a way to retrieve the authorization code which is necessary to obtain the refresh token.

Has anyone discovered a way to obtain the authorization code using Google One Tap login? Alternatively, are there any other methods to acquire a refresh token using the ID token?

Comment: one tap is sign-in authentication which gives id token.  Oauth2 is authorization and gives access token and refresh token.